# How to repeat query for a range of data in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google

I have this table in Google sheet:

| Col A (Month) | Col B (Date) |
| --- | --- |
| January | 1/1/2023 |
| January | 1/2/2023 |
| January | 1/3/2023 |

And I have another table:

| Col C (Dept.) | Col D (KPI) |
| --- | --- |
| Dep1 | KPI1 |
| Dep1 | KPI2 |
| Dep2 | KPI3 |

I want to repeat the first table for each item from the second table to be like:

| Col E (Month) | Col F (Date) | Col G (Dept.) | Col H (KPI) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 1/1/2023 | Dep1 | KPI1 |
| January | 1/2/2023 | Dep1 | KPI1 |
| January | 1/3/2023 | Dep1 | KPI1 |
| January | 1/1/2023 | Dep1 | KPI2 |
| January | 1/2/2023 | Dep1 | KPI2 |
| January | 1/3/2023 | Dep1 | KPI2 |
| January | 1/1/2023 | Dep3 | KPI3 |
| January | 1/2/2023 | Dep3 | KPI3 |
| January | 1/3/2023 | Dep3 | KPI3 |

I tried to work with query inside an array formula but it is not working.

Please Help,

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce()`, like this:

```
=query( 
  lambda( 
    table1, table2, 
    reduce( 
      A1:D1, sequence(rows(table1)), 
      lambda( 
        result, rowIndex, 
        { 
          result; 
          byrow( 
            table2, 
            lambda( 
              table2row, 
              { 
                index(table1, rowIndex), 
                table2row 
              }
            ) 
          ) 
        } 
      ) 
    ) 
  )( 
    filter(A2:B, len(A2:A)), filter(C2:D, len(C2:C)) 
  ), 
  "order by Col4 format Col2 'M/d/yyyy' ", 1
)
```

Comment: This is amazing, Thanks